# How can i store that the pushButton is pressed, then wait until "millis() - changeTime >= 10000", and then call the function changeLights()?

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I'm making an interactive traffic light with three LEDs for cars and two LEDs for pedestrians. These pedestrians have a pushbutton so that they can request a green light. Standard setup is always green light for cars (10 seconds) and red for pedestrians (5 seconds). Right now my code only allow pedestrians to use the pushbutton and get a green light AFTER the cars have had their green light for 10 seconds.

My question is how can I store that the pushbutton is pressed within the 10 seconds, and call my function `changeLights()` after these 10 seconds is up without waiting.

My code:

```
void loop() {
    int buttonState = digitalRead(pushButton);

    if (buttonState == HIGH && millis() - changeTime >=
        10000){
        changeLights();
      }
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here.  Please clarify the question.

Comment: @Alessando You want to know how to get `changeTime` first?

Comment: Im making an interactive traffic light with three LEDs for cars and two LEDs for pedestrians. These pedestrians have a pushbutton so that they can request a green light.

Standard setup is always green light for cars (10 seconds) and red for pedestrians (5 seconds). Right now my code only allow pedestrians to use the pushbutton and get a green light AFTER the cars have had their green light for 10 seconds. I guess my question is how can i store that the pushbutton is pressed within the 10 seconds, and call my function changeLights() after these 10 seconds is up without waiting

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a couple of variables: one to keep track of whether the pedestrian has pushed the button (`pedestrianIsWaiting`), and the other is the time when the pedestrian pushed the button (`changeTime`).

Each time the `loop` function is called, check the button. If the button is pressed and the pedestrian isn't already waiting, then change `pedestrianIsWaiting` to true, and record the time in the `changeTime` variable.

Then while the pedestrian is waiting, check the elapsed time. If it's been 10 seconds, call the function, and change `pedestrianIsWaiting` back to false.

The code looks like this:

```
bool pedestrianIsWaiting = false;
unsigned long changeTime;

void loop()
{
    int buttonState = digitalRead(pushButton);
    if (buttonState == HIGH && !pedestrianIsWaiting)
    {
        pedestrianIsWaiting = true;
        changeTime = millis();
    }

    if (pedestrianIsWaiting)
    {
        unsigned long elapsedTime = millis() - changeTime;
        if (elapsedTime >= 10000)
        {
            changeLights();
            pedestrianIsWaiting = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great, but what if a pedestrian requested a green light five seconds after the car got his green light. Then id like the pedestrian to only wait five seconds before they get their green light. Right now pedestrians ONLY get green 10 seconds after they requested it. If the car had his green light for 10 or more seconds, id like the pedestrian to get the green light right away.

Comment: Really in a time pressure here, otherwise i wouldnt really be asking... so it would be great... but thanks anyways!

Comment: @Alessando When you have the time, be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Also, visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), especially the part about what to do [when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Good luck with the project!